# I have problem scraping a 'title' attribut from an html class using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I need to take out the 'title': NAPAPIJRI Дуксер Burgee.

Here is my code.

```
html=BeautifulSoup(raw_html,"html.parser")
cardtitles=html.select(".product-link")
```

HTML:

```
</a>,
 <a class="product-link" href="https://www.buzzsneakers.mk/dukser/211933-napapijri-dukser-burgee" title="NAPAPIJRI Дуксер Burgee ">
 <span>подетално</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the tags' attributes

```
cardtitles=html.select(".product-link")[0]['title']
```